# How do I calculate non-natural logarithms in Racket?

Tags: lisp, scheme, racket

I am aware of racket's `log` function, which computers the natural logarithm of a number. I am trying to find the logarithms of numbers raised to arbitrary bases. In other words, instead of this:

```
> (log 9)
2.1972245773362196
```

I would like to do something similar to this:

```
> (logarithm 3 9)
2
```

Is there a function anyone knows about either builtin to Racket or available in a module from PLaneT I can use like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Racket 6.9.0.1 added a second argument for arbitrary bases. log<sub>k</sub>n can now be written as `(log n k)`.

According to the docs, this is equivalent to `(/ (log n) (log k))`, but possibly faster.

[log entry in the documentation.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=log#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._log%29%29)

Answer (score 16):

Use math: log<sub>k</sub> n = ln n / ln k:

```
(/ (log 9) (log 3))
```

Comment: `(expt b (* x y))` is equivalent to `(expt (expt b x) y)`. Since logarithms are the inverse of exponentiation, this explains why the formula works. This was high school algebra when I took it 35 years ago.

Comment: I just taught logarithms in a US college course last term. Currently, some people but not others learn about logarithms in high school.

Comment: It was indeed taught to me in high school--and hence, was completely forgotten about by the time I had to use this fact as a 5th year college student.